# how to read particular nodes from xml file using php

Tags: php

Here is the structure of the XML file am trying to fetch...

```
<feed>
    <entry>
        <id>1347030</id>
        <title>abcd</title>
        <description>xyz</description>
        <brand>mnop</brand>
        <link>http://www.abcd.com/1.html</link>
        <image_link>http://www.abcd.com/1.jpg</image_link>
     </entry>
</feed>
```

This is a small snippet of the XML...the file is huge...so am using XMLReader

I want to fetch the

> image_link

and

> link

nodes from this XML feed. To achieve this I have done the following code.

```
$xmlDocument = "test.xml";
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($xmlDocument);
while( $xml->read() ) {
if($xml->name == "image_link") {
    echo $xml->link ."<br/>";
  echo "<a href='".$xml->link."'><img height='80' width='100' src=" .$xml->readInnerXML()."></a><br />";
$xml->next();
}
}
```

This returns me the image but the link node is not fetched....any suggestion how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load('in2.xml');
    echo $doc->saveXML();
    $sImageLink = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'image_link' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
    $sLink      = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'link' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;

    var_dump( $sImageLink );
    var_dump( $sLink );
?>
```

For multiple records:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load('in2.xml');
    // echo $doc->saveXML();

    $oEntries = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'entry' );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $oEntries->length; ++$i )
    {
        $aImageLinks[] = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'image_link' )->item( $i )->nodeValue;
        $aLinks[]      = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'link' )->item( $i )->nodeValue;
    }
    var_dump( $aImageLinks );
    var_dump( $aLinks );
    // file_put_contents( 'in2.xml', $doc->saveXML() );
?>
```

Using XMLReader:

```
<?php
    $sInFile = 'in2.xml';
    $oXml = new XMLReader();
    $oXml->open( $sInFile );

    while( $oXml->read() ) 
    {
        if( $oXml->name == 'link' ) 
        {
            echo $oXml->readInnerXML();
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        if( $oXml->name == 'image_link' ) 
        {
            echo '<a href="';
            echo $oXml->link;
            echo '"><img height="80" width="100" src="';
            echo $oXml->readInnerXML();
            echo '"></a><br />';
            $oXml->next();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Vladimir...thanks for such prompt reply but I can't use DOMDocument...as the file is larger am using XMLReader only. Also I have to use some loops here...

Comment: Added multiple record handling/looping. I've had bad experiences/limitations while working with XMLReader so DOMDocument is my preferred traversal of xml files.

Comment: @Vladimir...thanks but with larger files DOMDocument is showing some error

Comment: echo "<a href='".$aLinks[i]."'><img height='80' width='100' src=" .$aImageLinks[i]."></a><br />"; this returns me blank result though

Comment: Updated to use XMLReader. Let me know if that solves your issues.

Comment: @Vladimir...it prints the link and image link but I want to display links as image...so i did the following code which didnt work...

Comment: @vladimir...if( $oXml->name == 'link' ) 
        {
            $i = $oXml->readInnerXML();
            //echo '<br/>';
        }
        if( $oXml->name == 'image_link'  ) 
        {
            echo '<a href="'. $i. '"><img height="80" width="100" src="'. $oXml->readInnerXML(). '"></a><br />';
            $oXml->next();
        }   I have tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feeds>
    <feed>
        <entry>
            <id>1347030</id>
            <title>abcd</title>
            <description>xyz</description>
            <brand>mnop</brand>
            <link>http://www.abcd.com/1.html</link>
            <image_link>http://www.abcd.com/1.jpg</image_link>
         </entry>
    </feed>
    <!-- more feed elements continue -->
</feeds>
```

I would use the [Essence](https://github.com/impensavel/essence) data extraction library in the following way:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Impensavel\Essence\XMLEssence;
use Impensavel\Essence\EssenceException;

$config = array(
    '/feeds/feed/entry' => array(
        'map'      => array(
            'image' => 'string(image_link)',
            'link'  => 'string(link)',
        ),
        'callback' => function ($data) {            
            echo sprintf('<a href="%s"><img height="80" width="100" src="%s"></a><br />', $data['properties']['link'], $data['properties']['image']);
        },
    ),
);

try
{
    $essence = new XMLEssence($config);

    $essence->extract(new SplFileInfo('feeds.xml'));

} catch (EssenceException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

This library can easily handle very large XML files (I've used it with files with more than 1GB).